# Can you identify this plug type?

Tags: identification, plug

I have a Koolatron SmartKool Cooler Freezer with a plug I can't identify.  I could use some help!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that one of the less common IEC 60320 plugs, maybe?

Comment: The closest match is the IEC 60320 C11 but that spec was withdrawn from the standard.  I think it is something else.

Comment: looks like a variation of IEC 60320 C17 Connector ... or a two prong version of IEC 60320 C15

Comment: I'd call that a cable socket rather than a plug. Your title and post don't mention whether it's mains or low voltage DC.

Comment: It is 12V DC.  Runs off a car cigarette lighter port.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is "IEC 320 C11 Connectors". This is very close to what you have posted.